# Converting max operator in the objective of LP into standard form

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

How do I convert the following objective (to be minimized)

$$\max_{} \left\{ f(x_1), f(x_2), \dots, f(x_{10}) \right\}$$

into standard form in the context of linear programming?

I didn't write the constraints as I assume they are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can linearize the minimax objective by introducing a new variable $z$ and minimizing $z$ subject to $z \ge f(x_i)$ for all $i$.